# How To Add A Div Next To An Image?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to add  divs on both sides of the image. I'm trying to make two yellow 
 horizontal rectangular  divs on both sides.

Comment: Be more specific than that! Add the code of what you've done so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` boxes in CSS. Read about it here: [FLEX-BOX](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
Fiddle here: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lphf2hwz/1) *Thank you to  Alon Eitan for his valuable suggestion!*
So, encapsulate your entire `div` with a parent `div` and then you can play around with the heights and width.
 
So your structure will be like:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="div1">

    </div>
    <div id="img1">
      <img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/HKwhBJp.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is good, but I suggest `width:calc((100% - 50px) / 2);` for the side divs to make them the same width (example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lphf2hwz/1/) - `50px` is the width of the image in your demo

Comment: @AlonEitan wow, I never knew that CSS could do that. I've replaced the fiddle link with yours. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the image in a `div` and use pseudo-elements

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(141, 0, 0);
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}

.image-container:before,
.image-container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

.image {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/World_topic_image_Satellite_image.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your requirement should be starting somewhere what this image is showing below. You can tinker around with it to get the layout which you need[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
#container{width:100%;height:100%; background-color: white;}
#left{float:left;width:100px;height:100px;background-color: yellow;}
#right{float:right;width:100px;height:100px;background-color: orange;}
#center{margin:0 auto;width:100px;height:100px;background-color: violet;}
</style>
<div id="container">
<div id="left">Your Left Div</div>
<div id="right">Your Right Div</div>
<div id="center">Image Goes Here</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not responsive and a nightmare to maintain, you don't clear float anywhere and fixing it using static height style. The other answer, with flex is the correct one (But still need improvements)